# How to import SSH-Library on RIDE?

Tags: robotframework, robotframework-sshlibrary

I'm going to do SSH connection using RIDE in VM.

To do so, I had to call SSH Library, but it failed.

How to import SSH Library call successfully?

i try

a. https://github.com/robotframework/SSHLibrary (Fail)

b. cmd > pip install robotframework-SSHLibrary (Fail)

c. cmd > pip install -U robotframework-sshlibrary==3.8.0 (Fail)

reference

https://github.com/robotframework/SSHLibrary

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zr8ejSgBgNU

help me plz

Comment: You did not add exact error that you are getting, so please update the question with more details on failure, so folks can assist you.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can download the source distribution from PyPI, extract it, and install it using one of the following depending are you using Python or Jython:

python setup.py install
jython setup.py install

Answer (score 0):

I tried with python3. If you notice there are some dependent libraries, which has to be installed first.

python3 -m pip install robotframework-sshlibrary

Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable

Collecting robotframework-sshlibrary

Downloading robotframework-sshlibrary-3.8.0.tar.gz (51 kB)

```
 |████████████████████████████████| 51 kB 128 kB/s
```

**Requirement already satisfied: robotframework>=3.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (from robotframework-sshlibrary) (3.0.4)

Requirement already satisfied: paramiko>=1.15.3 in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (from robotframework-sshlibrary) (2.10.1)

Requirement already satisfied: scp>=0.13.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (from robotframework-sshlibrary) (0.13.2)

Requirement already satisfied: pynacl>=1.0.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (from paramiko>=1.15.3->robotframework-sshlibrary) (1.5.0)

Requirement already satisfied: bcrypt>=3.1.3 in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (from paramiko>=1.15.3->robotframework-sshlibrary) (3.2.0)

Requirement already satisfied: six in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (from paramiko>=1.15.3->robotframework-sshlibrary) (1.16.0)

Requirement already satisfied: cryptography>=2.5 in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (from paramiko>=1.15.3->robotframework-sshlibrary) (2.9.2)

Requirement already satisfied: cffi>=1.4.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (from pynacl>=1.0.1->paramiko>=1.15.3->robotframework-sshlibrary) (1.15.0)

Requirement already satisfied: pycparser in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (from cffi>=1.4.1->pynacl>=1.0.1->paramiko>=1.15.3->robotframework-sshlibrary) (2.21)**

Building wheels for collected packages: robotframework-sshlibrary

Building wheel for robotframework-sshlibrary (setup.py) ... done

Created wheel for robotframework-sshlibrary: filename=robotframework_sshlibrary-3.8.0-py3-none-any.whl size=55119

sha256=63c5bf6b17e0ecbcd45f32b8a1ea367cfc0a19d2f17601a49b4f632472c68177

Stored in directory: /home/.cache/pip/wheels/c9/c2/39/2571d47c551e3012fa4e8284bbdcac2d025db39c275b058db4

Successfully built robotframework-sshlibrary

Installing collected packages: robotframework-sshlibrary

Successfully installed robotframework-sshlibrary-3.8.0